# WinForms - Creating and populating a DataGridView with a List of unknown number of columns

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

Hello everyone

I really don't know if I gonna be able to explain myself, but here we go:

I made a winforms app that capture prices for same products in different stores. The code is already optimized in a way I can add more stores.

The product class is something like this:

```
    public enum EnumMercado { Extra = 1, Dia = 8, Carrefour = 9, BIG = 10, Pao = 11 };
    public class Produto
    {
        public EnumMercado Mercado { get; set; } 
        public string IDProduto { get; set; }
        public string NomeProduto { get; set; }
        public bool Disponivel { get; set; }
        public decimal? Preco_de { get; set; }
        public decimal Preco_por { get; set; }
        public Bitmap ProductImage { get; set; }
        public bool Erro_Captura { get; set; }
        public String ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public Produto()
        {
            Erro_Captura = false;
            ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

And here is the class that I use to populate a single product search:

```
    public class PesquisaGeral
    {
        public PRODUTOS Produto { get; set; }
        public List<Produto> Cotacoes { get; set; }
        public PesquisaGeral()
        {
            Cotacoes = new List<Produto>();
        }
    }
```

PRODUTOS is a Entity class (Product ID on SQL and Name of the product in SQL)
Cotacoes is a List of Produto (for each store which this product is linked)

To get a full products x prices I have a List of PesquisaGeral

Now the question begins

In my DataGridView i want to populate in this way:

Headers:
[Product], [Name of the store 1], [Name of the store 2], [Name of the store 3]....[Quantity]
Values:
[Product 1] [2.66] [2.94] [1.98].....[editable text box]

I already made this work with a DataTable, creating the columns dynamically according to the number of the stores, plus the name of the product and the quantity.
that's "OK"

Is there a way to accomplish this regardless of using a DataTable?
Is it possible to dynamically create a List that will count the number of stores and create the number of named objects (perhaps anonymously) in a horizontal way?

What I want to accomplish is something like this:
*just to remember: public enum EnumMercado { Extra = 1, Dia = 8, Carrefour = 9, BIG = 10, Pao = 11 };*
var a = getmyCotacoes();
If I point the mouse in the running response, I want to be able to see a "List of something" that each something will show as (probably a list of anonymous):
Produt:"Product 1"
**Extra:2.1 

Dia:2.15

Carrefour:3.7

BIG:2.1

Pao:2.25**

Quantity:0

Today I have those stores but this will increase and I don't want to change the method every time I add a store.

btw, sorry about my English, I'm Brazilian.

thx in adv

Rafael

Comment: If you bind the DGV to a proper DataSource it can create the columns itself

Comment: That's exactly what I expect to do, but before that, I need to create the proper DataSource, which is the  meaning of this question: How to create an adequate List to add as a DataSource to my DGV when this List can have a variable number of columns (properties). In other words, is not a List of a know class

Comment: How do you get all these data? from Database? from some service?

Comment: JohnG, you are correct, I can't bind a list of stores to create the columns. The reason I don't want to work with a DataTable is that I have an additional column named "Quantity", which is user editable in the DGV. After the user add the quantity of each item and proceed to "Check Out" I will have to iterate through the DataTable, join the original Search Results (that took me to the DataTable) to continue my work. If I had a dynamic class or a anonymous (Can't figure out how to use it or if is even possible to bind such kind of class to a DGV), I could just use it from start to finish.

Comment: Chetan Ranpariya, all products and stores are saved in SQL, including urls for connection, retrieve product details and etc. The program runs a HttpWebRequest for each product / Store each time the user wants to refresh the products list, bringing most affordable prices for each product in each store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment about not wanting to use DataTable doesn't make sense; datatables/datarows can be subclassed to create a custom class just like you do with your proposed solution of List , so you get all the functionality of a datatable plus whatever you want from your custom class. Visual studio even has a built in device for creating custom datatables and datarows so that a strongly typed data access layer can be built (usually for a db but doesn't have to be)

The comment about having to join the original search results doesn't make sense either; a datatable is not your database table, and can contain fewer or more columns than your database does. For example, your select might be `SELECT ID as ProductId, Nome, Preco FROM products WHERE Nome LIKE 'Jamon%'` so, three columns, and your datatable might have columns `ProductId, Nome, Quantidade, Preco, PrecoTotal` so 5 columns, and PrecoTotal could have an Expression of `"[Preco] * [Quantidade]"` so it calculates automatically. The quantity column is not retrieved by the query, so the user fills it in. The total only calculates when the quantity is filled in..

I think when it comes to the problem of whether to use or not use datatables, it's more that you aren't quite using them correctly or fully understand how they work; I'm certain they can solve your problem but so we just need to nail down the actual problem

---

Your actual question seems to be "how do I have a variable number of shops" - that's gonna be pretty hard if you keep your shops in an enum (MercadoEnum) because enums are compiled into the program. To add a new shop you'll have to release a new program. Instead your shop should be a table in the db, like your product is. You should have another table linking shops to products and the price a particular product would be stored in this table because even though every shop might sell milk, they all sell at different prices. When you query your ships and prices you essentially get a list of products back that are the same product, and a bunch of different prices but critically *you get the prices back as rows* - if 5 shops sell a product you get 5 rows. If two shops sell a product you get two rows back. You're saying you want these as *columns* - we typically call this a pivot, where we turn a variable number of rows into a variable number of columns. Be careful when you do this, because it's not always wise. Columns are typically thought of as the attributes of a thing, and things don't typically have an infinitely variable number of attributes -
modelling them as such can make them harder to work with

In this case it's still possible; you have a column for the price in each shop, and you perform the pivot either in the db or in the code, maybe by having a datatable with the product I'd as the key, and add a new column every time you encounter a shop you don't know about. You'll end up with one row per product with a column set of prices in each shop. If you have multiple products then you might have a lot of blanks if not every shop sells every product

---

Note that when I say shop I mean "nation-wide chain of shops" - I recognize Carrefour in that mercado list and they have a lot of locations and maybe even every branch sells some products differently. Perhaps even the product linking should be done at a branch level (a building in a town) rather than group-of-shops level, to allow different locations to stock different products at different prices

---

Your first problem is not "datatable can't do" one, it's a data modelling one; you haven't quite got the data modelling right for your program yet